# Convert C# Sha1 to php

Tags: c#, php, character-encoding, sha

I am trying to convert a c# code to php but since I am from a php background I am unable to find the relevant code.
Here is the code.

```
  static string sha1Hash(string password)
    {
        return string.Join("", SHA1CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)));
    }
```

I tried use **sha1()** of php but the output is very different.c

Comment: Were the bytes passed into `sha1()` the same as the bytes being passed into `ComputeHash()`? Sorry, not super familiar with PHP or its `sha1()` method..

Comment: The Sha1 hashing algorihtm is fed with a stream of bytes. In this case, it is the value of a string are represented in UTF-8. Are you certain that is the identical bytewise representation of it in PHP?

Comment: Can you give an example password and output in C#?